# What's the equivalent of R sample function in Stata

Tags: random, stata

I have a basic question about Stata. I have programming experience in R but I've started a new job where Stata is the main language. I'm currently diving into Stata on my own and sometimes it's hard to understand how to do simple things.

I've trying to get 5 random numbers between 3 and 50 but without success.

In R, any of these would work:

```
 floor(runif(5, min=3, max=50))
 16 39 11 11  5 # output

 sample(3:50, 5, replace=TRUE)
 28 13  5 36 19 # output
```

But I'm not sure how to do this in Stata, specifically how to return random numbers within the desired range (3:50). Any pointers would be appreciated. I found the `runiform()` function but I don't think I can get the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
set obs 5
generate rnum = runiform(3, 50)
```

You are basically creating a dataset first and then generating a variable with the desired properties.

Comment: Hi, thank you. That's probably what I'm looking for but I get an error `invalid syntax`. I got the idea that `runiform` doesn't take arguments and returns values between 0 and 1.

Comment: In that case, you're using an out-of-date version of Stata. (In asking Stata questions it's always a good idea to explain which version you're using if it's not the latest, as I write 15.1.)  But the work-around is easy: `3 + 47 * runiform()` is drawn from a uniform distribution with  limits 3 and 50.

Comment: There is a `floor()` function in Stata as in R. If you want random integers from a uniform on 3(1)50 that could be `floor(3 + 48 * runiform()`

Comment: Hi @NickCox, you're right I forgot to state the version. I'm using Stata 13 and yes I'm looking for integer results. I realised it was best to add an output of what I was looking for as Stata users may not be familiar with the `sample` in R.

Comment: Thank you @NickCox! The work-around works perfectly.

Comment: There is a parenthesis to be added in my last comment.