# Keep data in memory when importing file Stata

Tags: memory, import, stata

I'm trying to write a simulation program. However, since I'm new to Stata I'm doing each step at a time and slowly in order to understand how Stata works. Adjustments will be done once I understand more about Stata.

The idea is to create a vector/list of numbers (some specific and other random) and pass that vector as argument to the `mvrs` command. I will then run a simulation to find the pattern of knots with the smaller AIC. More information can be found in the Spika et al. BMC Cancer (2017) paper.

Thanks to the StackOverflow community I was able to generate random numbers (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441167/whats-the-equivalent-of-r-sample-function-in-stata)). But I'm having problems importing the Excel file afterwards. **Is there a way to keep the random numbers created and open the Excel file?** When I try to run the code I get `no; data in memory would be lost r(4);` after trying to import the Excel file.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
* Create list of specified knots
local spec_knots 0.5 1 2 84.5

* Create random knots between 3 and 50
set obs 3
gen vals = floor(3 + 47 * runiform())
* Save levelsof vals and save to local to join specified and random knots
levelsof vals, local(values)

* Join specified and random knots to include in the mvrs command
local list_knots `spec_knots' `values'

import excel file, sheet("Analysis") firstrow

mvrs glm deaths age, family(poisson) exposure(population) all scale(1) alpha(1) knots(`list_knots')
```

My plan is to include the above code in a program and then run a simulation. Something along these lines:

```
simulate aic=aic bic=bic dev=dev, reps(10) nodots: knots_location
```

Using `scalar aic = e(aic)` before the end of the program.

Any pointers to keep the random numbers and importing the file are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start by importing the Excel file, then you can get three random numbers later from Mata without needing to create any new variables. Or you could do it the other way round.

```
import excel file, sheet("Analysis") firstrow

* Create list of specified knots
local spec_knots 0.5 1 2 84.5

* Create random knots between 3 and 50
mata : st_local("values", invtokens(strofreal(floor(3 :+ 47 * runiform(1,3)))))

* Join specified and random knots to include in the mvrs command
local list_knots `spec_knots' `values'

mvrs glm deaths age, family(poisson) exposure(population) all scale(1) alpha(1) knots(`list_knots'
```

Alternatively, so long as you know that your file has at least 3 observations, your program could start

```
import excel file, sheet("Analysis") firstrow

* Create list of specified knots
local spec_knots 0.5 1 2 84.5

* Create random knots between 3 and 50
gen vals = floor(3 + 47 * runiform()) in 1/3 
levelsof vals, local(values)

* Join specified and random knots to include in the mvrs command
local list_knots `spec_knots' `values'
```

You have a small probability that 2 or even 3 of your random numbers coincide.

Comment: Thank you! I also tried the other way around but wasn't able to `set obs 3`. I only looked at `mata` briefly to create matrix. So, if I understood correctly the `strofreal` converts the values created by `floor(3 :+ 47 * runiform(1,3))` into three strings and `invtokens` concatenates the three strings into 1 string. Is that it?

Comment: Not quite. `strofreal()` in this case converts a numeric vector to a string vector; then `invtokens()` combines the elements of the string vector into a single string scalar.

Comment: I can't see any code showing where you used `set obs 3` but (a) I didn't suggest that (b) it will fail if you already data in memory with more than 3 observations. A golden rule here is to show code that fails, not talk about it.

Comment: Sorry. Language barrier. I meant before posting the question I tried importing the file before `set obs 3`, which is in the code I posted. Your code works fine. It was just a comment addressing that I had the issue b. I didn't say you mentioned that. Thank you for the explanation!